# same command using exec giving different output

Tags: java, apache, centos6, apache-tika

I am migrating from one server to another and see that the same exec command gives different output. I am not sure what i need to check and ensure so that i see consistent output

```
Example of the command that is executed:



java -jar /var/www/html/PhpTikaWrapper-master/vendor/tika-app-1.5.jar -m one.jpg
```

1) Server 1(This is what i want)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Chroma BlackIsZero: true
    [1] => Chroma ColorSpaceType: RGB
    [2] => Chroma NumChannels: 4
    [3] => Compression CompressionTypeName: deflate
    [4] => Compression Lossless: true
    [5] => Compression NumProgressiveScans: 1
    [6] => Content-Length: 9371
    [7] => Content-Type: image/png
    [8] => Data BitsPerSample: 8 8 8 8
    [9] => Data PlanarConfiguration: PixelInterleaved
    [10] => Data SampleFormat: UnsignedIntegral
    [11] => Dimension ImageOrientation: Normal
    [12] => Dimension PixelAspectRatio: 1.0
    [13] => IHDR: width=150, height=75, bitDepth=8, colorType=RGBAlpha, compressionMethod=deflate, filterMethod=adaptive, interlaceMethod=none
    [14] => Text TextEntry: keyword=Software, value=Adobe ImageReady, encoding=ISO-8859-1, compression=none
    [15] => Transparency Alpha: nonpremultipled
    [16] => height: 75
    [17] => resourceName: Orca-logo.png
    [18] => tEXt tEXtEntry: keyword=Software, value=Adobe ImageReady
    [19] => tiff:BitsPerSample: 8 8 8 8
    [20] => tiff:ImageLength: 75
    [21] => tiff:ImageWidth: 150
    [22] => width: 150
)
```

Server 2(This is what i am getting in new server):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Comments: Lavc56.5.100
    [1] => Component 1: Y component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 2 horiz/2 vert
    [2] => Component 2: Cb component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
    [3] => Component 3: Cr component: Quantization table 0, Sampling factors 1 horiz/1 vert
    [4] => Compression Type: Baseline
    [5] => Content-Length: 25259
    [6] => Content-Type: image/jpeg
    [7] => Data Precision: 8 bits
    [8] => Image Height: 840 pixels
    [9] => Image Width: 840 pixels
    [10] => Jpeg Comment: Lavc56.5.100
    [11] => Number of Components: 3
    [12] => Resolution Units: none
    [13] => X Resolution: 1 dot
    [14] => Y Resolution: 1 dot
    [15] => comment: Lavc56.5.100
    [16] => resourceName: ankita2_comp.jpg
    [17] => tiff:BitsPerSample: 8
    [18] => tiff:ImageLength: 840
    [19] => tiff:ImageWidth: 840
    [20] => w:comments: Lavc56.5.100
)
```

Java version on both server is same and as follows

```
java version "1.7.0_141"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.10.1.el6_9-x86_64 u141-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.141-b02, mixed mode)
```

Also, the command does not return width on the new server.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `exiftool` installed on both?

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue, actually apache tikka provide different format of response for different file type provided.

For JPEG we will get a different response and for png we will get a different response as i was getting above.

Hope this saves someones time in future.